# How to set a default input value for Onsen prompt dialog?

Tags: angularjs, dialog, alert, prompt, onsen-ui

I'm using Angular and Onsen to develop a cross-platform app. I would like to use Onsen prompt dialog to get input from users.

Here is my code:

```
function inputName() {
    $rootScope.ons.notification.prompt({
        message: "What is your name?",
        callback: function(name) {
            service.userName = name;
        }
    });
}
```

This is an example from the Onsen documentation for Alert, Confirm and Prompts: http://codepen.io/onsen/pen/Qwwxyp

I would like to show a starting value in the prompt which users can edit but there's nothing in the documentation, is there any way to do this?

[image]

Comment: Since you are using angular, just use:  `<ons-input value="{{your_variable}}" ......./>`

Answer (score 0):

There is placeholder parameter in options

```
options.placeholder:'foo'
```

Answer (score -1):

you can set `defaultValue` key of options for a prompt like
`defaultValue: 'your value'`